# Raspberry PI not booting and no lights

Tags: boot-issues

I was working on my new RPi 2 Model B yesterday when it shut off mid-use and wouldn't turn back on.  I was in the middle of testing a project with a breadboard and believe that I mixed a wire or otherwise crossed a 5v connection with another connection.

I'm not sure exactly what happened, or even how it might have happened, but it no longer shows any lights when power is connected and appears to have the correct voltage coming into and even after the polyfuse. I've also tested other power supplies, just to make sure.

I gave it a few hours before attempting to power it on, but it didn't show any lights.  The SOC does get hot, which may be a bad sign.

Is it dead or should I give it a few days for the polyfuse and see what happens?

If it is dead, is there anything I can do in the future to prevent this (besides being more careful)? This is my first foray into RPi and I don't want to keep running into the same issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I give it a few days for the polyfuse and see what happens?

I guess your choices are a) Give it a few days, b) Give up now. At least one person here has reported busting one, throwing it in the closet, and then finding it worked again months later.  Not that the polyfuse would take that long, but there you go.  Unfortunately...

> The SOC does get hot, which may be a bad sign.

Yes, probably.  If it were the polyfuse, I don't think that would happen.  It would just be off.

> is there anything I can do in the future to prevent this (besides being more careful)?

No. It is a fairly delicate piece of electronics, so whatever you do to prevent this boils down to "being more careful".

Comment: I'll give it a few days and report back.  In the future, I will definitely be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is dead, is there anything I can do in the future to prevent this (besides being more careful)?

One thing I have experienced in my short time working with the Raspberry Pi is that you should always make breadboard changes with the Pi powered down, double-check to make sure you don't have cross-connections, then power up. Though I'll admit that can be frustrating and time-consuming, especially when the change is a very quick one.